# Distinguish $p'$-elements in a coset

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with a nonabelian minimal normal subgroup $N$.
Then $N$ is a direct product of $n$ copies of some nonabelian simple group $S$.
Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $|S|$ and let $xN\in G/N$ be of order not divisible by $p$ ($xN$ is called a $p$-regular element of $G/N$).

**My question is: Is there a way to detect $p$-regular elements in the coset $xN\subseteq G$? or could we measure the number of $p$-regular elements inside $xN$?**

Any explanation, references suggestion and examples are appreicated.

Comment: One useful fact is that the number of $N$-conjugacy classes of $p'$-elements in $xN$ is the same as the number of $x$-invariant conjugacy classes of $p'$-elements in $N$. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.2238.pdf, Lemma 2.2.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. @SeanEberhard.